# How to obtain embedded representation of single test instance after training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, word2vec

The first layer of my RNN is embedded layer as follows.

```
visible = Input(shape=(250,)) 
embed=Embedding(vocab_size,50)(visible)     
x2=keras.layers.GRU(224, return_sequences=False)(embed)
predictions=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x2)
```

I train this network and predict some output.

Now after training, I test it on my test data which is very straight forward.

I want to know the exact embeddings of my test data or for the sake of implementation, embeddings of any of my test sequence after the model has been trained. I want to use those embedding in some other application. Is there any way to extract those embedding for my test sequence data after the training?

Try: Let's say my model is m, the I obtain the embedding weights as follows.

```
embeddings = m.layers[1].get_weights()
```

I also have a reverse dictionary `reverse_char_map` as follows.

```
{1: 'c',
 2: 'C',
 3: '(',
 4: ')',
 5: 'O',
 6: '=',
 7: '1',
 8: '2',
 9: 'N',
 10: '3',
 11: 'n',
 12: '[',
 13: ']',
 14: 'S',
 15: '4',
 16: '-',
 17: 'l',
 18: '+',
 19: 'H',
 20: '5',
 21: 'F',
 22: '.',
 23: '#',
 24: 's',
 25: 'o',
 26: '6',
 27: 'P',
 28: 'B',
 29: 'r',
 30: 'a',
 31: '7',
 32: 'e',
 33: 'I',
 34: 'i',
 35: '8',
 36: 'u',
 37: 'K',
 38: '9',
 39: 'R',
 40: '%',
 41: '0',
 42: 'Z',
 43: 'h',
 44: 'L',
 45: 'A',
 46: 't',
 47: 'd',
 48: 'G',
 49: 'M',
 50: 'g',
 51: 'U',
 52: 'b',
 53: 'T',
 54: 'W',
 55: 'p',
 56: 'V'}
```

I don't know how to use `embeddings` with `reverse_char_map` to obtain embeddings for one of the test input sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the above layers, like so:

```
visible = Input(shape=(250,), name='visible') 
embed=Embedding(vocab_size,50,name='embed')(visible)     
x2=keras.layers.GRU(224, return_sequences=False, name='x2')(embed)
predictions=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='final')(x2)
```

Then, the model composed of these layers (let's call it m1), may be used to initialize a new model, where you can refer to these layers, like so:

```
def evaluation_model(training_model):
    visible = training_model.get_layer('visible')
    embed = training_model.get_layer('embed')
    output = embed(visible)
    m = Model(inputs=[visible], outputs=[output]
    m.compile(..)
    return m

em = evaluation_model(m1)
```

Alternatively, you could simply pop the final few layers of your initial model, or also have it output the embeddings but without any loss.

Comment: My goal is to obtain the embedding for one test sequence only. For the time being, I am not using my weights for the first model in some other model. I do have a "reverse word to index" dictionary , but I don't know how to use it. I have edited the question.

Comment: You shouldn't be removing the embedding weights, but rather feeding a character index sequence into the model and using the model's output (i.e. the embeddings). If for some reason you want to do it the hard way, you would need to convert each character index into a 1-hot vector of size `vocab` and you would then get the embeddings via vector-matrix multiplication (one-hot vectors against the weight matrix).